# Get partial results of map function

Tags: list, haskell

Is it possible to get the partial results of the map function in Haskell?
So if i use map this would be the normal result:

`map (+1) [1,1,1]
[2,2,2]`

But I want this as a result:
`[[2,1,1],[2,2,1],[2,2,2]`

Is this possible to get this result with a buildin function or do I have to make a new function for myself?

Comment: I know of none such function - so I guess you have to do it yourself (or wait and see if someone knows one)

Comment: That by itself doesn't seem useful&general enough to warrant having a dedicated standard function for it. It's simple enough to define it yourself, so probably you should just do it. But, what do you actually need this for? Perhaps we can point to a more general alternative approach (sounds like a scan of traversal might be the right thing).

Comment: @leftaroundabout, it's rather easy with `para`: `fun f = para (\x xs r -> map (f x :) (xs : r)) []`.

Comment: @user3237465: how about you guys get a proper SO account with a readable username instead of a magic number? And, that solution with `para` sounds interesting, why don't you make it an answer?

Comment: @leftaroundabout, I'm a magician. The question doesn't ask about a solution directly, so I decided to leave a comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must make a new function for yourself.